# LSI megaraid - config raid and non-raid

Tags: raid, ibm, lsi, megaraid

I have this configuration of server

- IBM X3650 M4
- IBM ServeRAID M5110e
- 300GB x3 SAS (config as RAID 5)
- 1TB x1 SAS (config as normal disk, non-raid)
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

I would like the system behave like the following:

- OS install in the RAID-5
- Temporary data in the 1TB

I have successfully setup the RAID 5 using the ServerGuide disk. 
However I cannot find a way to setup the non-raid disk of the 1TB

Can I do this?
If not, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out you can configure a single disk RAID-0 to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say either a separate raid0 on single disk. Or you could always use a nas or external interface such as eSata if you ran out of hard drive bays.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I needed to connect temporary a drive with data partition on it.

Thus I can confirm that creating RAID0 LogicalDrive which consists from one physical drive will allow to access the data from it.

Attach drive to LSI MegaRAID (my case it was 84xxx model) and from command line (Unix/Linux headless server) run:

`MegaCli -CfgLdAdd -r0[253:4] -a0`

Here is: r0 - RAID 0, a0 - adapter 0 (first).